# Спецсимволы в консольном приложении в C#

Tags: c#, кодировка, консоль

Здравствуйте, господа!

Возникла необходимость вывода в консольное приложение на C# спец.символов. Например -  "┌" (рамка, левый верхний угол).
ASCII код 218. Но на выходе получаю "Ú".

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SomeString);
bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866"), bytes);
char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bs.Length; i++)
        chars[i] = (char)bytes[i];

Console.Write(new String(chars));
```

Я так понял что перед 218 добавляется "0". Например если набрать в консоли Alt+218 то получаем нужный символ "┌", а если Alt+0218 то "Ú".

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Не понял смысл вашего кода. Что вы хотели сделать с его помощью?
Из предполагаемых ошибок: конструктор String принимает массив Char'ов в Юникод формате, а они у вас содержат cp866 коды; в цикле вообще происходит что-то жуткое: в юникод-строках каждый символ кодируется больше чем одним байтом, а вы работаете с массивом bytes побайтово.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы знаете код символа в кодировке Х и хотите вывести его на консоль, для начала нужно сформировать побайтовое представление строки в кодировке Х. Для cp866 это несложно ибо каждый символ кодируется одним байтом:

```
byte[] a = {218};
```

Теперь конвертируем в Юникодные Char'ы и выводим:

```
Char[] chars = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866").GetChars(a);
Console.Write(chars[0]);
```